# Radio button change text on click CSS jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

Currently I'm trying to change the text color when clicking on a radio button. This is working, but it has to change back whenever another one is selected. I can't get this to work, whatever I'm trying. I thought this was the best way to get my problem solved.

This is the code I'm currently using: (Radio buttons)

```
<div class="checkboxes">
<label class="container"><div class="checkboxcijfer">1</div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container"><div class="checkboxcijfer">2</div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

The jQuery (I have removed all things I've tried. I followed a tutorial where they also removed the class to the siblings. Unfortunately this isn't working. This makes the color of the item change:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.container [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

        $(this).prev().addClass('red')

    });
    });
```

And the easy CSS:

```
.white
        {
            color: #FFF;
        }
```

[So here is how it currently works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNCv0.png)

[And this is what's going wrong when clicking away.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyFK3.png)

Comment: I'm not sure how this logic is working at all.  Your radio buttons do not have a previous sibling that `prev()` would find.

Comment: @Taplar, wouldn't it go up through the DOM in that case?

Comment: no, prev() is a immediate previous sibling selector  http://api.jquery.com/prev/  it goes sideways, not up the dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the element with class `.red`, and remove the class:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $('.red').removeClass('red');
    $(this).prev().addClass('red')

  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label class="container">
    <div class="checkboxcijfer">1</div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label class="container">
    <div class="checkboxcijfer">2</div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

If you can switch the `input` and the `div`, you can have a CSS only solution using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
input:checked + .checkboxcijfer {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <div class="checkboxcijfer">1</div>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="radio">
    <div class="checkboxcijfer">2</div>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much. So many hours spent for such a small thing. This seems very logic and it works. Not sure what my brain was thinking after seeing this. Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried the same with the CSS. Just didn't knew I had to change the positions of the div and input. Good to know for the next time.

Comment: You're design is perfect for the CSS only solution, since the input is hidden anyway. Just switch the places.